# $c_0$, $l_1$, $l_\infty$ and duals

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Why $$ (l_1)^{**}=l_1 \oplus (l_\infty/c_0)^*   $$ Is there any general isomorphism between $X$,$X$** and $X$*** in  Banach spaces?